# write text in a shape of heart

Tags: fontsize, french

I want to write a text in a shape of heart, but I met a problem because of the French character.

```
\documentclass[12pt,svgnames]{article}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}  % langue
\usepackage{fontspec,microtype,shapepar,xcolor}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Chorus}
\begin{document}
\textcolor{black}{\heartpar{Au symbole de dou-ceur, de tendresse, d’amour et d’affection, ma mère pour son soutien incessant. A
mon père, pour les sacrifices qu'il a consentis
pour mon éducation. Que ce travail soit le
témoignage de l'amour que je lui avoue. A
mes chers amis qui m'ont soutenu, encouragé et m'ont surtout permis
de travailler dans une atmosphère joviale.
}}
\end{document}
```

I got this result :
[image]

but I want to have this result, what should I do ?
[image]

Comment: Write `\\`e` to obtain è.

Comment: Do not use `inpuutenc` and `fontspec` if you are using xelatex or lualatex just save the file in utf-8 and don't load inputenc then make sure you have saved in utf-8 not latin1  (iso-8859-1) If you are using pdflatex use `inputenc` but don't use `fontspec`

Comment: I deleted some of your tags such as tikz-pgf which didn't seem relevant to the question

Comment: You can simplify your file a little by removing `[svgnames]`, `xcolor`, and `\textcolor{black}{…}` since you want black text.

Comment: I edited my publication

Comment: If I understand your edited question correctly, all you need to do is change `\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Chorus}` to the font you prefer.  For Latin Modern, just use `\usepackage{lmodern}`, for EB Garamond use `\setmainfont[Contextuals=Alternate,Ligatures={TeX,Rare},ItalicFeatures={Ligatures=Contextual}]{EB Garamond}`, etc.

Comment: You should remove the hyphen in “dou-ceur” and let babel take care of French hyphenation.